# ValueError trying to split the lines of a text file

Tags: python, string

This is my code:

```
def MusicGame():
score=0
tries = 0
with open("songs.txt") as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
        artist,name=line.split(" - ", 1)
        question=(artist + "- " + " ".join([x[0].upper() for x in name.split()])+": ")
        answer=input(question)

        if tries != 2:
            if answer in ["STOOPID","Funky Friday","dark knight dummo","natural disaster","gucci gang"]:
                print("well done")
                tries=0
                score=score+3

            elif answer not in ["STOOPID","Funky Friday","dark knight dummo","natural disaster","gucci gang"]:
                    answer2=input("it was wrong try again")

                    if answer in ["STOOPID","Funky Friday","dark knight dummo","natural disaster","gucci gang"]:
                        print("well done+1")
                        tries=tries+1
                        score=score+1
                    elif answer2 not in ["STOOPID","Funky Friday","dark knight dummo","natural disaster","gucci gang"]:
                        print("you suck you lost")
                        break
```

I keep getting this error

```
artist,name=line.split(" - ", 1)
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

My text file looks like this:

> 6ix9ine,Bobby Shmurda - STOOPID
>
> Dave,Fredo - Funky Friday
>
> Trippie Redd,Travis Scott - Dark Knight Dummo
>
> NSG - Natural Disaster
>
> Lil pump - Gucci Gang

Comment: Please provide content of `songs.txt`. So far it looks like you have inconsistent data, that can't be unpacked into 2 variables

Comment: OK? Since we can't run your code to reproduce the error, what is your question here?

Comment: Add a `print(line)` just above `artist,name=line.split(" - ", 1)` and you'll see that some of the lines in the file don't have the **" - "** substring.

Comment: What is in your songs.txt file?

Comment: @slam songs.txt is where the song names are stored for example when run the first question is 6ix9ine,Bobby Shmurda - S: and the respone is STOOPID then it shows the error only when the question is right

Comment: @mRotten the song names for example it looks like this                
 6ix9ine,Bobby Shmurda - STOOPID

Dave,Fredo - Funky Friday

Trippie Redd,Travis Scott - Dark Knight Dummo

NSG - Natural Disaster

Lil pump - Gucci Gang

Comment: @iiTrixo Examples of your file are worthless because we want to find the line that produces the error. We need the file.

Comment: @iiTrixo yes, thanks!

Comment: @iiTrixo I would really like you to stop trying to vandalize my answer through editing, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your file has empty lines. You can't split those on `'-'` and unpack the result into two variables because these lines don't contain that character. Filter out the empty lines first.

Demo:

```
>>> def non_blank(file):
...     return (line for line in file if line.strip())
... 
>>> with open('songs.txt') as songs:
...     for line in non_blank(songs):
...         print(line.split(' - '))
... 
['6ix9ine,Bobby Shmurda', 'STOOPID\n']
['Dave,Fredo', 'Funky Friday\n']
['Trippie Redd,Travis Scott', 'Dark Knight Dummo\n']
['NSG', 'Natural Disaster\n']
['Lil pump', 'Gucci Gang\n']
```